# How do I detect if Gevent's monkey-patching is active?

Tags: python, gevent

I have a Python unittest that depends on `multiprocessing` and therefore must not run when Gevent's monkey-patching is active. Is there a Python statement that can tell me whether `gevent.monkey.patch_all` has run or not?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not sure there is an idiomatic way, but one simple way would be to check the  `socket.socket` class:

```
import gevent.monkey, gevent.socket
gevent.monkey.patch_all()
import socket

if socket.socket is gevent.socket.socket:
    print "gevent monkey patch has occurred"
```

Comment: Just a slight suggestion, the more pythonic way would be: `if socket.socket is gevent.socket`

Comment: @WesMason Thanks, that is good. It'd have to be `if socket.socket is gevent.socket.socket` though.

Answer (score 13):

afaik the `gevent.monkey.saved` dict is only updated when an item is patched, and the original is placed within the dict (and removed on unpatching), e.g.

```
>>> from gevent.monkey import saved
>>> 'sys' in saved
True
```

Comment: Hi Wes! This is a good idea, but I'm going to accept the other answer because it works back to Gevent 0.13, whereas "saved" appeared in Gevent 1.0.

Comment: By looking into `monkey.saved.keys()` after running `monkey.patch_all()`, I don't think the `"sys"` key is in it. This is not a valid way to detect monkey-patching.

Comment: If there is *anything* in `saved` then monkey patching is in effect.

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I used for detecting if gevent monkey patching is active.

```
def is_gevent_monkey_patched():
    try:
        from gevent import monkey
    except ImportError:
        return False
    else:
        return bool(monkey.saved)
```

As [A. Jesse Jiryu Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/618967/a-jesse-jiryu-davis) mentioned, this works for gevent 1.0.x only.

*Updated:* in gevent 1.1 there's [an support API](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html#querying) that is helpful to know if objects have been monkey-patched. So the answer for gevent 1.1 could be:

```
def is_gevent_monkey_patched():
    try:
        from gevent import monkey
    except ImportError:
        return False
    else:
        return monkey.is_module_patched('__builtin__')
```

BTW, I find that `monkey.is_module_patched('sys')` always returns `False`. By looking into `monkey.saved.keys()` after running `monkey.patch_all()`, I think only the following modules are valid to check:

```
['_threading_local', '_gevent_saved_patch_all', 'socket', 'thread', 'ssl', 
 'signal', '__builtin__', 'subprocess', 'threading', 'time', 'os', 'select']
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice addition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check a socket instance

```
def is_socket_patched(sock):
    return sock.__module__.startswith("gevent")
```